# libcURL code not working, says I'm uploading to the server w/out a file name

Tags: objective-c, c, libcurl

While working on an FTP uploader using , I encountered a strange error that is really stumping me. I've gone through the documentation, and I'm really confused. It's connecting to the right server, because of the output displayed in verbose mode, but then it dies with the following error in the console:

```
* Entry path is '/'
* Uploading to a URL without a file name!
* Closing connection #0
* URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

Here's the code:

```
int upload_music_file(const char* music_file, const char* short_music_file) {
strcpy(DESTINATION_MUSIC_FILE, music_file);
strcpy(REMOTE_MUSIC_FILE, short_music_file);

[musicFileField setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", DESTINATION_MUSIC_FILE]];
[curFileProgress setDoubleValue:0];

CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;
FILE *hd_src;
struct stat file_info;
curl_off_t fsize;

/* get the file size of the local file */
printf("Destination music file: %s\n", DESTINATION_MUSIC_FILE);
if(stat(DESTINATION_MUSIC_FILE, &file_info)) {
    printf("Couldn't open music file %s: %s\n", DESTINATION_MUSIC_FILE, strerror(errno));
    return 1;
}
fsize = (curl_off_t)file_info.st_size;

#ifdef DEBUG
printf("Local music file size: %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T " bytes.\n", fsize);
#endif

[curFileProgress setMaxValue:(double)fsize];

/* get a FILE* of the same file */
hd_src = fopen(DESTINATION_MUSIC_FILE, "rb");

/* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

/* get a curl handle */
curl = curl_easy_init();
if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://orangesquirrels.com/");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    printf("UPLD MUSK: Remote URL: %s\n", REMOTE_URL);

    /* we want to use our own read function */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, music_read_callback);

    /* enable uploading */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

    /* specify target */
    printf("Remote Music File: %s\n", REMOTE_MUSIC_FILE);
    fflush(stdout);
    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, REMOTE_MUSIC_FILE);

    /* pass in that last of FTP commands to run after the transfer */
    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE, headerlist);

    /* now specify which file to upload */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, hd_src);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, (char *)loginUser);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, (char *)loginPassword);

    /* Set the size of the file to upload (optional).  If you give a *_LARGE
     option you MUST make sure that the type of the passed-in argument is a
     curl_off_t. If you use CURLOPT_INFILESIZE (without _LARGE) you must
     make sure that to pass in a type 'long' argument. */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE,
                     (curl_off_t)fsize);

    /* Now run off and do what you've been told! */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "UPLD MUSK: curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
        if (strcmp("Remote file not found", curl_easy_strerror(res)) != 0) // The file won't exist since we're creating it.
        {
            [SBErrorNotice performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showError:) withObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:curl_easy_strerror(res)] waitUntilDone:NO];
            //[SBErrorNotice showError:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:curl_easy_strerror(res)]];
            errorOccurred = true;
        }
    }

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}

fclose(hd_src); /* close the local file */

curl_global_cleanup();
return 0;
}
```

Here's the full console output (username and password struck out):

```
Destination music file: /Users/user/Music/button-1.mp3
Local music file size: 10498 bytes.
UPLD MUSK: Remote URL: ftp://orangesquirrels.com
Remote Music File: button-1.mp3
* About to connect() to orangesquirrels.com port 21 (#0)
*   Trying 50.63.71.1...
* connected
* Connected to orangesquirrels.com (50.63.71.1) port 21 (#0)
< 220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
< 220-You are user number 9 of 500 allowed.
< 220-Local time is now 15:23. Server port: 21.
< 220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
< 220 You will be disconnected after 3 minutes of inactivity.
> USER -------
< 331 User ------- OK. Password required
> PASS -----------
< 230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
> PWD
< 257 "/" is your current location
* Entry path is '/'
* Uploading to a URL without a file name!
* Closing connection #0
* URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
UPLD MUSK: curl_easy_perform() failed: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you set the URL you must specify also the filename. Replace:

```
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://orangesquirrels.com/");
```

with:

```
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://orangesquirrels.com/myfile.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. After making some tweaks to concatenate the strings, everything worked out fine.